# Selecting fallback database in Django3

Tags: django, nginx, django-database

My Django3 project works in docker using gunicorn+nginx. That connected to remote DBSaaS
postgresql cluster: main side + standby side (ReadOnly if not active).

How to use another database when the main one is unavailable?

This DB setting in my Django3 project now:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'db_main',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': "!!!!",
        'HOST': '1.1.1.5', # MAIN DB
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Now, if db_main host is unreachable. I manually set another IP in settings (like 1.1.2.4)
And relaunch my site.
What settings\middle should i use for decide this problem?
It necessary for full redundant for my project

Surfing not helps me. That docs don't cover my case:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/multi-db/

Please, give me some links\hints for that. May be there is no native\3rd-party Django-solutions.

Should i use nginx scenarios for solve it?
Something like:

nginx periodically checks postgresql ip availability and if active side is unreach it goes change my settings.py file or import another env variable DATABASE?